# facebook og:title

Tags: facebook, addthis

Why doesnt facebook Object Debugger pick up on y og:titls and og:discriptions when it already shows it in my src code???

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Was the moon landing real in 1969" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.opinionfreaks.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.opinionfreaks.com/images/logoMain.png" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Was the moon landing real in 1969" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="opinionfreaks" />
```

when i run the same link trough Object Debugger it just wont show them....any ideas...

Kind regards

Ronan

Comment: The the URL http://www.opinionfreaks.com currently answers with an HTTP status code `401 Unauthorized` might have _something_ to do with it, don’t you think …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: had to dynamicly create the 
           og:url ...http://www. opinionfreaks.com?user_id =343&title=
...seems to have worked a treat

Answer (score 0):

What @CBroe said essentially.

Your server needs to be accessible to the public web, or have a exclusion in your blocking rules for the Facebook Crawler. There's more details in the [Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/#facebook_scraper).

Comment: Cheers for the reply guys, but I had access open for testing and that's when I noticed the problem, I have since blocked the site...

Comment: What was the debugger telling you? It'll usually report back some kind of error message.

Comment: Its not giving me an error....it just shows an empty title and description string, how ever, I think i know whats wrong...I'm dynamically creating the titles and descriptions from links...so when I bebug from Facebook there's no title or description being called...that's all I can think of...Dont know if I'm right but it sounds logical.......